# Publishing winform application with .sql files

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

Maybe someone can help me with the following problem:

I created a winform application in visual studio which i want to publish. The application contains a map Sqlscripts with .sql files in it.

```
 FileInfo file = new FileInfo("../Sqlscript/View.sql");
            string SQLscript = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
```

i thought about creating a  directory for those files in C:\ when running the application, but ten i realized that it's not safe doing it this way. No one should have acces to sql querys. Can anyone help me for an alternate?

Thanks!

Comment: You can encrypt (and compress) it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Do you have any suggestions to do that in this situation?

Comment: Well there are multiple types of encryption. People can however just decompile your project and get it.... you can also add it as a resource and load it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embed your .sql file as resource (i.e, file content will be embedded in compiled code), and read it at runtime with `Properties.Resources.yourresourcename`

```
string sql = Properties.Resources.yourresourcename;
```

To add a file as resource, open Resources.resx in solution explorer -> Add Resource -> Add existing file (or add new text file)

Answer (score 0):

Obscurity != security. If someone wants to, they can always get the contents of the file. Be it reverse engineering, or simply reading out the memoty of the program. How important is it that thay can't edit / view the SQL? Otherwise I would generate the SQL on a server somewhere. Make sure the server only accepts parameters and generates / runs the SQL there.